# Combining quiver and imagesc

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to combine a quiver plot and `imagesc`, here is my script:

```
x=[0    0.0125    0.0250    0.0375    0.0500,
     0    0.0125    0.0250    0.0375    0.0500,
     0    0.0125    0.0250    0.0375    0.0500,
     0    0.0125    0.0250    0.0375    0.0500,
     0    0.0125    0.0250    0.0375    0.0500];

 y=[0         0         0         0         0,
0.0125    0.0125    0.0125    0.0125    0.0125,
0.0250    0.0250    0.0250    0.0250    0.0250,
0.0375    0.0375    0.0375    0.0375    0.0375,
0.0500    0.0500    0.0500    0.0500    0.0500];

vx=[0.0009   -0.0019   -0.0058   -0.0040   -0.0028,
0.0012    0.0159    0.1207    0.1465    0.0985,
0.0007    0.0018   -0.0367    0.2432   -0.0053,
0.0004    0.0920    0.1796    0.3807    0.0338,
-0.0006    0.1708    0.1764    0.2567    0.1256];

vy=[0.0002    0.0000   -0.0001   -0.0001   -0.0001,
-0.0003   -0.0156   -0.0076   -0.0251   -0.0433,
-0.0008   -0.0113   -0.0218   -0.0519   -0.0720,
-0.0006   -0.0091   -0.0326   -0.0778   -0.1087,
-0.0003   -0.0026   -0.0025   -0.0416   -0.1048];


vz=[0.0002    0.0000   -0.0001   -0.0001   -0.0001,
-0.0003   -0.0156   -0.0076   -0.0251   -0.0433,
-0.0008   -0.0113   -0.0218   -0.0519   -0.0720,
-0.0006   -0.0091   -0.0326   -0.0778   -0.1087,
-0.0003   -0.0026   -0.0025   -0.0416   -0.1048];

figure(1)
imagesc(vz)
hold on

step = 2;
quiver(x(1:step:end,1:step:end), y(1:step:end,1:step:end), vx(1:step:end,1:step:end), vy(1:step:end,1:step:end), 'ShowArrowHead','on', 'AutoScaleFactor',1) 
hold off
```

If I just use `quiver(vx,vy)` it works and they are combined, but there are too many arrows and I would like to tweak the quiver plot.

However, when I manually change the parameters as in the example, combining them doesn't work. Is it possible somehow to combine them anyway?

Comment: "doesn't work" ? PC explodes in 1000 pieces? error? everything is amber color?

Comment: I cannot make it work with step=1 either, so how do you make them work together?

Comment: When I just use `quiver(vx,vy)` then it works fine. If I explicitly set the step then only `imagesc` is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the quivers are somewhere else.

Your x and y are all about `0.05` maximum size, but when you use `imagesc` every pixel is `1` size, so your quiver are there somewhere, very very very small in the bottom left corner.

if you want to make them on top of the image you are going to need to change `x` and `y` values, but its quite easy. Replace the quiver call by:

```
quiver((x(1:step:end,1:step:end))*(size(vz,1)-1)/max(x(:))+1, y(1:step:end,1:step:end)*(size(vz,2)-1)/max(y(:))+1, vx(1:step:end,1:step:end), vy(1:step:end,1:step:end), 'ShowArrowHead','on', 'AutoScaleFactor',1)
```

[image]

Also note that your axis are wrong, they show 1:5 but should show something else.

Comment: you can also define the x and y limit of your image with: `imagesc([x_min x_max],[y_min y_max],vz)`.

Comment: @obchardon oh... didn't know about that. Consider adding it as an asnwer!